# React Native Auth0: "Authorization has been denied for this request"

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth, authorization, auth0

I am using react-native-auth0 v1.6.0 to authorize my React Native app to access an API. The Auth0 server is successfully returning an access token, but shortly after I get the following "Authorization has been denied for this request" screen:

[image]

The code in which I call the auth0.webAuth.authorize() method is as follows:

auth0.webAuth.authorize({
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    audience: 'http://localhost:54423/'
})

Does anyone have insight into how to troubleshoot this?